# Writing to single file from mappers in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to write to a single file from multiple mappers. It is possible in synchronous/serialized fashion? I have `n` number of mappers. Here `n` is chosen by the user during run time.

Comment: It would help, if you add more information to your question, like the input, expected output etc.

Comment: thanks for quick reply!    I have file lets say file1 which containing numbers (for example 1,2,3,4,5,6 ... etc). now file 1 will split in fragment.Corresponding to each fragment ,one  mapper is there.mapper will take fragment and perform some operation on number  and writing on temp file. like that each mapper will perform some operation on input fragment n each mapper  will write into temp file...now after finishing job of each mapper we will delete file 1,then create file 1 and copy data of temp file into file 1..this file 1 will again giving as input to mappers in next iteration...so on..

Comment: here i don't want to give data to reducer..because large data we have to send to reducer then reducer will write on single file

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you do not want to use a reducer. You want all the mappers to write their output to a single file. I am not sure, if this is possible. I need to check.

Comment: no i am using reducer for another task....problem is like each mapper is finding local maximum as well as updating input data by applying some function..so here mapper have two out put...1. one  local maximum for all input  2.update data corresponding to each input..so mapper will give local maxima to reducer using clean up method,and mappers will write updated data into temp file.

Comment: why do not use 1 reducer?

Comment: i got another solution. i am using multiple output file concept.each mapper will generate file which will be merge into one file

Comment: Ramin Dərvişov : sir i mention that i dont want to move large data from mapper to reducer...only local maximum will output of each  mapper to reducer

Comment: private MultipleOutputs<NullWritable,Text> multipleOutputs;
public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {   context.getTaskAttemptID().getTaskID().getId();
   if(multipleOutputs==null){
    
    multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs(context);
   }
  }
  
  
  public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {
        multipleOutputs.close();
  } 
  

//in mapper multipleOutputs.write(NullWritable.get(),value, key.toString());

Comment: for merging

String srcPath = "/mapperoutputholder"; 
   String dstPath = "/aftermerging1";
  
 
  try { FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf); FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), true, conf, null); //true means source file ko delete kr denge 
  } catch (IOException e) { }

Comment: before moving large data from mapper to reducera you can use combiner. Combiner works on where works mappers

Comment: dude i think u didn't read my requirement carefully. and one more point combiner will run  or not every time ,we can't say. number of combiner and run of combiner is internal part